# Spring security or LDAP server to rule password policy?

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

I have a application that use Jpa Hibernate,Spring Data, Spring security, but I want more control over password rules and users, for example, password expiration time, session time, inactive session time, etc. 
Spring security can do all these tasks automated?

Other possibility is to use LDAP, to control password policy, but I already have users defined in my application and I can't see how LDAP server can read my users to apply the polices, or the users have to be in the LDAP server to authenticate in my application?

I installed apacheds server to test.

I need to know if I'm using the right approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the LDAP password policy it will apply to existing users next time they change their passwords, and you can force them to do that.

Session inactive/expiry time has nothing to do with password policies as implemented in LDAP.

Comment: Thank you EJP, now I make my application connect to apacheds server and authenticate the user. Do you know a way that when I create a new user in my application create too in the apacheds server ? Most examples I found is only to authenticate

Comment: @DAM I don't know what you mean by 'create a new user in my application'. You should create it in the LDAP server only. You don't want two places to keep users.

Comment: Because I have a screen to create a new user, that generate the password and send it by e-mail, what I want to mean is that, when I create a new user I want to save on LDAP server, only. After a long  search I found a sample that show this at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/tree/master/samples.  Thank your for your help.